# How do I hide an empty ACF field on the frontend?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

**How do I hide an empty ACF field on the frontend?**

I am using a ACF url field that is not required. It should only display if the field has a value on the backend.

I am using the following function to call the field on he front end and to display as a button:

```
<div class="booknowbtn"><a href="<?php the_field('book_now_link'); ?>" target="_blank">Book Now</a></div>
```

It is displaying and working correctly if there is a url on the backend but needs to be hidden if the field is empty.

**Listing example with url value:**

https://rb.gy/8ybhm

**Listing example without a url value (Button needs to be hidden):**

https://rb.gy/tgcmp

I tried the following js which does not work:

```
*jQuery( document ).ready(function() jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    var button = jQuery( '.booknowbtn' );
    var link = button.find('a').attr('href');
    if(link == '' || link == undefined){
        button.hide();
    }
});*
```

Can anybody assist me with a function, php script or js?

(I am not a php developer)

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: Wrap the template code you got there into `<?php if(get_the_field('book_now_link')): ?>` and `<?php endif; ?>`, that should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide that part with if statement.

```
<?php if(get_field('book_now_link')){ ?>
<div class="booknowbtn"><a href="<?php the_field('book_now_link'); ?>" target="_blank">Book Now</a></div>
<?php } ?>
```

This code will not add button in frontend if there is no value set in backend.